# combining queries in SQL

Tags: sql

Attempting to return list of titles (t.processed) that exist in both MOF and SIL locations, and then subtract titles from that list that exist in SIL

Revised:

```
select t.processed, i.call
from item i, title t
where i.bib# = t.bib#
    and i.collection = 'PIC'
    and i.location in ('MOF', 'SIL')
except
select t.processed, i.call
from item i, title t
where i.bib# = t.bib#
    and i.collection = 'PIC'
    and i.location = 'SIL'
```

Unfortunately this returns no results, but it is a little closer to what I need

Sample output is fairly simple (and flexible):

```
processed        call
Mouse count      P WAL
Fly away home    P BUN
```

To further clarify:  I would like to find the titles (ex. Fly away home) that are repeated in both the SIL and MOF locations, and then remove from that list the titles that occur in the SIL location

Comment: Doesn't your second query do that?

Comment: Seems like your second query should give you what you want.  If you want both, then `AND (i.location = 'STL' OR i.location = 'MOF')` should work

Comment: The question is asking for products that are in MOF and not in SIL, not for the union of the two.

Comment: Given the various confusion, I highly recommend updating the OP with some actual data (unless one of the answers is already sufficient) that replicates your problem.

Comment: The 2nd query would work if there were only two locations.  I want to include MOF and SIL excluding all other locations and THEN exclude SIL

Comment: I believe it was my error to try to include item# in the select statement because the item# will differ between locations.  t.processed should be the same, however

Comment: Let me ask this.  Are you looking for all items that exist in ONLY the MOF location and thus you mention subtracting the "SIL" location?  Or... You want anything that is MOF only OR SIL, but not a MOF AND SIL?  Totally different queries.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I'd like a display of titles from both locations first, then subtracts titles that occur in SIL

Comment: @Marc, I suggest you clarify further then.  How is that different from including all MOF locations, and then excluding all containing SIL locations?  What's special about your data that requires searching for both first?

Comment: sorry perhaps I should start over:  I would like a display that lists all titles (t.processed) that are in both locations, then remove all titles from that same list that are in the SIL location

Comment: Please revert the last edit - you've taken out all of the useful information from your question :)

Comment: Sample data and sample output would REALLY help here.  So you want one output that is all items/etc. that have rows in BOTH `SIL` and `MOF`, or EITHER?  Then you want a second output that has only `MOF` and no `SIL`?

Comment: I may be overthinking this...

Comment: IUf you want titles im both loactions (this means it has to be in both) and remove those that are also in SIL, then that removes all of them. Your logic is clearly not correct.

Comment: You are almost certainly overthinking this.  The set of [SIL|MOF]&[!SIL] is equal to the set of [MOF]&[!SIL].

Comment: Yes you are correct.  My question was poorly worded.  I'll post my solution as soon as I can (insufficent rep)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Item is something like

```
ID Item Collection Location
1  1    PIC        MOF
2  1    PIC        SIL
3  2    PIC        MOF
4  3    PIC        SIL
```

then

```
Select select mof.item#, mof.call, mof.collection From Item mof
Left Join Item sil On mof.Item# = sil.Item# and sil.Collection = mof.Collection
Where sil.Location = 'SIL'
and mof.Location = 'MOF'
and mof.Collection = 'PIC'
and sil.ID is null
```

will get you close. Stop with the old join syntax...

Answer (score 0):

The [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator does this, for some flavors of SQL at least:

```
select i.item#, t.processed, i.call, i.collection
from item i, title t
where i.bib# = t.bib#
    and i.collection = 'PIC'
    and i.location = 'MOF'
except
select i.item#, t.processed, i.call, i.collection
from item i, title t
where i.bib# = t.bib#
    and i.collection = 'PIC'
    and i.location = 'SIL'
```

Comment: What does the second part of this query actually add, there are no SIL in the first set so no need to exclude any!

Comment: Given the question, I assume the source data has multiple rows for i.bib# that may have different locations; so this returns rows that have items in MOF but not also in SIL.

Comment: Joe's assumption is correct.  However, this still is not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select i.item#, t.processed, i.call, i.collection
from item i, title t
where i.bib# = t.bib#
    and (
         (i.collection = 'PIC' and i.location <> 'SIL') 
         or ( i.collection = 'PIC' and  i.location = 'MOF')
        )
```

Comment: This will include all MOF and everything that is not SIL, which would be MOF, ABC, XYZ etc. Not what is require methinks (Did you edit after my original comment!)

Comment: The two i.location expressions seem redundant, even if the interpretation of the question this answer assumes is right.

Comment: I corrected it to return list of _all items that are in i.location 'MOF' but not in i.location 'SIL'_ as mentioned in question

Comment: Same problem, just reversed

Comment: What rows could possibly be returned or not returned by this that aren't also returned by `and i.location='MOF'`?

Comment: I understand what you say but I don't know the how the tables are structred and i dont know how the data is in the tables. I am trying to answer the question from the what is mentioned in the question

Comment: Understood, but I don't think from a simple logic standpoint that your answer makes any sense regardless of the data.  Your most recent edit at least is not redundant code, but you're not really aiming towards the question.

Answer (score 0):

FINAL EDIT:

This would be the query I was looking for (my apologies for not explaining myself adequately)

```
select t.processed
from title t, item i
where t.bib# = i.bib#
and i.location = 'MOF'
and i.collection = 'PIC'
and i.bib# not in (select bib# from item where location = 'SIL' and collection = 'PIC')
```

I am still having trouble wrapping my head around subqueries.  My trouble was in not using the primary key `i.bib#` as the basis for the subquery.

Thanks all for your suggestions!